# C struct issues

Tags: c, struct, buffer

Here is my code.
I do not know how to use structs in C. Can someone take a look to see what my why I am getting an error on this? I dont usually code in C and was told I might need to use a pointer in this.

```
 #include <pthread.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   #include <assert.h>


   struct Buffer
        {
            int link;
            char message[30];   
        }buffers[3];

    //5 philosopher boxes and one available
    int boxArray[6] = {0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

    buffers[0].link = 1;
    buffers[0].message = "empty";

    buffers[1].link = 2;
    buffers[1].message = "empty";

    buffers[2].link = -1;
    buffers[2].message = "empty";

    void sendMessage (int philNum, char newMessage)
        {
            int header;

            header = boxArray[0];

            boxArray[0] = buffers[header].link;

            buffers[header].message = newMessage;

            if (boxArray[philNum] == -1)
                {
                    boxArray[philNum] = header;
                    buffers[header].link = -1;
                }

            else 
            {
                int i = boxArray[philNum];
                int temp;

                do  
                {
                    temp = buffers[i].link;

                    if (temp == -1)
                    {
                        buffers[i].link = header;
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        i = buffers[i].link;
                    }
                }while (temp = -1);

            }
        }
```

Output. I dont understand what the issue is here

```
Message.c:17:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
     buffers[0].link = 1;
               ^
Message.c:18:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
     buffers[0].message = "empty";
               ^
Message.c:20:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
     buffers[1].link = 2;
               ^
Message.c:21:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
     buffers[1].message = "empty";
               ^
Message.c:23:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
     buffers[2].link = -1;
               ^
Message.c:24:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
     buffers[2].message = "empty";
               ^
Message.c: In function ‘sendMessage’:
Message.c:34:28: error: assignment to expression with array type
    buffers[header].message = newMessage;
```

Comment: "I  do not know how to use structs in C". It's not great just to rely on others when you could take the time to look up a C book/tutorial for these basic issues.

Comment: That was profoundly unhelpful, thank you!

Comment: @kaylum s comment is exactly I was about to post, too. You should first learn the language before you bother others to fix and explain what you wrote. There are C books for free, if you don't want to spend money buying one. C is no language to learn with trial&error and we are not a tutoring site!

Comment: Same reason `int i[3]; i[0] = 5;` doesn't work outside of a function.

Comment: Ok, so what will you do when you inevitably encounter your next small error? Come running to Stackoverflow each time to ask basic questions that you can get answers to in countless other ways? Would it not be better to learn the language properly before attempting to use it and only ask others after you've exhausted all your own efforts at solving the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are *assignments*; you put them with global declarations, but they are not allowed outside of a function:

```
buffers[0].link = 1;
buffers[0].message = "empty";
buffers[1].link = 2;
buffers[1].message = "empty";
buffers[2].link = -1;
buffers[2].message = "empty";
```

You need to replace them with *initializers*:

```
struct Buffer {
    int link;
    char message[30];   
}buffers[3] = {
    {.link = 1, .message = "empty"}
,   {.link = 2, .message = "empty"}
,   {.link =-1, .message = "empty"}
};
```

The above uses C99 syntax of [*designated initializers*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/6wcXZT)

Answer (score 0):

It may little bit help you to understand how to assign string to struct member.

Try This:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Buffer
{
    int link;
    char message[30];   
}buffers[3] = {{1, "empty"}, {2, "empty"}, {-1, "empty"}};

//5 philosopher boxes and one available
int boxArray[6] = {0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

void sendMessage (int philNum, char newMessage)
{
    int header;

    header = boxArray[0];

    boxArray[0] = buffers[header].link;

    (void) memcpy(buffers[header].message, &newMessage, sizeof(newMessage));

    if (boxArray[philNum] == -1)
    {
        boxArray[philNum] = header;
        buffers[header].link = -1;
    }
    else 
    {
        int i = boxArray[philNum];
        int temp;

        do  
        {
            temp = buffers[i].link;

            if (temp == -1)
            {
                buffers[i].link = header;
            }

            else 
            {
                i = buffers[i].link;
            }
        }while (temp = -1);

    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Main called this sendMessage(): \n");
    sendMessage(2, 'C');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you may not place statements outside functions.

Thus these statements in any case are wrong

```
buffers[0].link = 1;
buffers[0].message = "empty";

buffers[1].link = 2;
buffers[1].message = "empty";

buffers[2].link = -1;
buffers[2].message = "empty";
```

And arrays do not have the assignment operator. So instead of that

```
buffers[0].message = "empty";
```

and othet similar statements as for example this

```
buffers[header].message = newMessage;
```

write

```
strcpy( buffers[0].message, "empty" );
^^^^^^^
```